# Escape "+" with JS and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, encoding

i have made an app,

you write some text, and text will be saved over ajax. Before sending the request, i escaped it with js. But somehow, the "+" Character will be converted to " " Space Character...

So i tryed to find and replace before sending in "%plus%" but i get thes error message:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+/: Nothing to repeat

Code:

```
var replace = "%plus%";
            while(title.search(sign) != -1) {
               title.replace("+", replace);
            }
```

Maybe some one know a better solution for this... i work with utf-8... and german characters like "ä" I have also Problems with "€" while getting it from DB over Ajax... and a lot other characters....

I have great results if i rawescape() in php and unescape() in js (but still have Problems with € -> %u20AC

Need help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So i tryed to find and replace before sending in "%plus%"

That is insufficient. If you're failing to URL-encode the `+` symbol, you are almost certainly forgetting to URL-encode anything, and there are many other characters that will cause failure if not URL-encoded than just the plus sign.

You need to use `encodeURIComponent()` when creating your request to encode special characters inside parameters:

```
var url= 'something?param='+encodeURIComponent(param)+'&other='+encodeURIComponent(other);
```

Otherwise, any characters that don't fit in URLs will cause corruption, including `+` (which means a space if included in a query parameter; for a real plus sign you'd need `%2B`) and many other punctuation symbols, as well as all non-ASCII characters (eg. `€` should be `%E2%82%AC`, using UTF-8 encoding).

**Do not under any circumstances use the JavaScript `escape()` and `unescape()` functions.** These are not URL-encoding, but a non-standard encoding peculiar to JavaScript that looks similar to URL-encoding but is not compatible. In particular all non-ASCII characters get mutilated, which is why `€` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4):

To match a `+` in regex, you need to escape it because `+` itself is a special character.

```
return theText.replace(/\+/g, "%plus%");
```

BTW, the proper encoding of `+` is `%2b`. You could use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_javascript_1.5_reference:global_functions:encodeuricomponent) for this, in Javascript. (Don't use [`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_Functions), it's deprecated.)

Comment: encodeURIComponent this ist the solution for my Problem! thx.

Comment: but now i have problems with german characters, what a function a have to use in php?

Comment: How do i encode the string in PHP correctly? If I do not encode, i get this A+B = Ã¶Ã¤Ã¼ ? Ã from "A+B = öäü ? ß"

Have you an idea?

Comment: @Fincha: I don't know what you mean. Maybe you should ask a new question.